Laravel 11: How to use "Has Many Through" through two models that have "pivot"?
I am using Laravel 11.
I searched a lot about this but I can't find a good solution. Of course, I may not have used the right expressions.
I have a model called A in which I have defined:
protected $primaryKey = 'pid';
This model is related to the L model as follows:
 public function speaker(): HasMany
 {
 return $this->hasMany(L::class, 'speaker_id', 'pid');
 }

It also has a many-to-many relationship with the T model through the pivot table (account_tag).
In model T we have:
 public function accounts(): BelongsToMany
 {
 return $this->belongsToMany(A::class, 'account_tag', 'tag_id', 'account_id', 'id', 'pid');
 }

Now I want to have a relationship between T and L so that T can directly access the speaker_ids' in L that are related to A that is related to T through account_tag'.
Apparently, I should use Has Many Through, but this code doesn't work properly in Model T:
 public function likes()
 {
 return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\L', 'App\Models\A', 'tag_id', 'pid', 'tags.id', 'accounts.pid');
 }

Additional explanation:
Yes. I can use query but I need to create relationship.

I've written an answer that explains why that cannot be done, but perhaps there is a different type of solution that does not rely in a direct relationship between T and L. Can you post the code that you're trying to run? Is it something like $t->likes()->create(...) ?

There's an external package that handles as hasManyThrough() via different intermediate tables called hasManyDeep(): https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep. It should work for your use case, but IGP's answer is correct; in default Laravel, this cannot be done on a belongsToMany() relationship.

HasManyThrough only works for 2 HasMany-type (one-to-many) relationships . For example:

if A hasMany B
and B hasMany C
⇒ you can define A hasManyThrough C (A has many C through B).

It does not work for belongsToMany (many-to-many) relationships
